# JQuery autocomplete very slow after a couple of passes

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

This is the code i'm using:

```
this.input = $( "<input>" )
      .appendTo( this.wrapper )
      .val( value )
      .attr( "title", "" )
      .addClass( "form-control ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
      .autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 0,
        source: ['first_element', 'second_element', 'third_element', ..., 'hundredth_element']
      })
      .tooltip({
        classes: {
          "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
        }
      });
```

The first couple of times it's fast, but from the 5th time on it gets real slow.

I tried to measure its performance with Google Dev Tools and Firefox's, it's this slow only in Google Chrome.

[EDIT]

Google Dev Tools suggest the performance's problem resides in "source", the sorting process done by jquery causes the script to hang for some seconds and everytime it runs, the "waiting time" increases exponencially.

Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Yeah, if you insert a [Runnable Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) into your question, I can check if I'm able to reproduce the issue in my Chrome DevTools.